# Getting slow when iterate for loop

Tags: ios, iphone

for ( NSDictionary *detailsDict in rsltArray)
    {
            NSString *OfficeId    =[detailsDict objectForKey:@"ObjectId"];
            NSString *catID       =[detailsDict objectForKey:@"catID"];
            NSString *ObjType     =[detailsDict objectForKey:@"ObjectType"];

```
        NSString *getImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select catMarkericon from TBL_Category where catID='%@'",catID];
        NSMutableArray * imageArray = [self.database getDataListBySQLQueryStatement:getImage];
        NSString *officeLogo  = [[imageArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"catMarkericon"];

        NSArray *parts = [officeLogo componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *filename = [parts lastObject];


        NSString *OfficeName;
        NSString *OfficeAddress;
        if([[UserDefaults getLanguageSelection]isEqualToString:@"en"])
        {
            OfficeName  =[detailsDict objectForKey:@"ObjectNameEnglish"];
            OfficeAddress  =[detailsDict objectForKey:@"ObjectAddressEnglish"];
        }
        else
        {
            OfficeName  =[detailsDict objectForKey:@"ObjectNameArabic"];
            OfficeAddress  =[detailsDict objectForKey:@"ObjectAddressArabic"];
        }

        double Off_lat      =[[detailsDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
        double Off_long     =[[detailsDict objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue];

        tempLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Off_lat longitude:Off_long];
        CLLocationDistance meters = [tempLocation distanceFromLocation:CurrentLoc]/1000;

        if(meters<=Dist)
        {
            [arrListdata addObject:detailsDict];
            if ([catID isEqualToString:selectID]) {
                tempCoordinate = [ARGeoMarkerco coordinateWithLocation:tempLocation locationTitle:OfficeName withid:OfficeId withaddress:OfficeAddress withimage:filename withcatId:catID withObjType:ObjType selectValue:YES newmarker:NO];
                [locationArray addObject:tempCoordinate];
            }
            else{
                tempCoordinate = [ARGeoMarkerco coordinateWithLocation:tempLocation locationTitle:OfficeName withid:OfficeId withaddress:OfficeAddress withimage:filename withcatId:catID withObjType:ObjType selectValue:NO newmarker:NO];
                [locationArray addObject:tempCoordinate];
            }

    }

}
```

i am using for loop like this and i have to iterate more than 1500 data and it getting 4 to 7 seconds that will stuck my application is any way to resolve this

Comment: You need to show more code. What do you *do* with each dictionary. The loop itself won't take much time at all.

Comment: Based on the information you gave us: Write efficient code and use efficient data structures.

Comment: NSEnumerator *e = [array objectEnumerator];
id object;
while (object = [e nextObject]) {
  // do something with object
}

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a background thread for that, to avoid blocking the main (UI) thread.

Comment: 1500 shouldn't be too big to do by brute force. What's in the dictionaries?

Comment: @trojanfoe yeah, but he'll still have the problem of it taking 4-7 seconds. Even if the UI was visible, that might still cause issues with usability if UIButtons and other interactivity is present and no data to work with it is ready.

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs Perhaps it's supposed to take 4-7 seconds?  Not everything can be done in 30ms.

Comment: i have edited and put full code inside the for loop plz check

Comment: How many categories do you have?  It seems likely that the time consuming activity is retrieving the category detail from the sql table (and using string interpolation on an SQL query is very bad practice from a security standpoint). If each entry doesn't have a unique category it seems like you could save a lot of time by simply loading all the categories into a dictionary before the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I have to write this in Objective C/pseudocode hybrid just to give you an answer as fast as I can.

Split the 1500 member array into 2.

```
NSRange theRange;
NSRange theSecondRange;
theRange.location = 0;
theRange.length = 749;
theSecondRange.location = 750;
theSecondRange.length = 750;    
NSArray *array1 = [rsltArray subarrayWithRange:theRange];
NSArray *array2 = [rsltArray subarrayWithRange:theSecondRange];
```

Then, create 2 dispatch queues in the background. Thread the first array out in the first queue with the code you have. Do the same with the second one. When the threads are finished, put them together using NSArray `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray`.

If it's still too slow, split the array further into 4 or 8 and thread those out on separate queues. The trick is that you have to wait to add them until the threads come back otherwise your app will crash because there won't be an array to add back into one main array.
Update see this link on Apple about dispatch groups in Grand Central Dispatch to deal with the situation I mentioned about when the subarrays get back https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19

Comment: If the tasks can be completed concurrently then it may be much simpler to use `dispatch_apply`

Comment: but my array is not a static one its related to api data in future it will be 5000 or above.

Comment: Then split the array like the docs do `theRange.length = [wholeArray count] / 2;` with a denominator that makes sense for your array length

Comment: i have applied your logic no change from current situation

Comment: @iosDev it's an issue with how your arrays come back after they come back from the thread. Basically your threads get executed concurrently but when they finish is not necessarily in the order that you want. Thread 1 could finish after thread 5 for example. How to deal with this situation is the hard part and depends on the design of the final data structure. You might want to ask a more specific question on SO about how to design a data structure or class that can accomplish this joining of the threads once they're done. It should be much faster than a serial execution on the main thread.